# Can anyone help me to understand this error

Tags: vb.net

Please help me for solving this error error

> Unable to write to output file 'C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\obj\Debug\WindowsApplication1.exe': The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.   WindowsApplication1

Comment: Plzz don't use silly abbreviations for words here.  This isn't facebook.  You can spell out the full word "please" without too much extra effort.

Comment: Usually it is good to give some background of what you are actually doing, not just an error msg.. However, here it looks like the program you want to compile (WindowsApplication1.exe) is running. Thus the .exe file can not be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

This means that either your exe is already running (perhaps outside the IDE) or it's been opened for editing in another application (debugger?).

Close the exe down and try again.